# How to create query open time slots between booked events for a set date and time?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I am attempting to create a query to list open time slots for a specific day. I have found many similar questions on here, but none of the answers seem to do the job.

A simplified version of my booked appointments table:

Table name: **app_bookings** (before output)

```
CREATE TABLE `app_bookings` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`client_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`provider_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`doctor_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`department_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`date` DATE NOT NULL,
`StartTime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`EndTime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`duration` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`payment` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`created_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`updated_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

);

```
INSERT INTO `app_bookings` ( `client_id`, `provider_id`, `doctor_id`, `department_id`, `date`, `StartTime`, `EndTime`, `duration`, `payment`, `created_by`, `updated_by` ) VALUES
 ( 1, 3, 11, 1, '2018-10-21', '2018-10-21 10:15:00', '2018-10-21 11:00:00', 0, '', 0, 0 ),
 ( 1, 3, 11, 1, '2018-10-21', '2018-10-21 11:15:00', '2018-10-21 13:00:00', 0, '', 0, 0 ),
 ( 1, 3, 11, 1, '2018-10-21', '2018-10-21 14:15:00', '2018-10-21 14:45:00', 0, '', 0, 0 ),
 ( 1, 3, 11, 1, '2018-10-21', '2018-10-21 15:00:00', '2018-10-21 15:45:00', 0, '', 0, 0 ),
 ( 1, 3, 11, 1, '2018-10-21', '2018-10-21 16:00:00', '2018-10-21 16:30:00', 0, '', 0, 0 );
```

**My current MYSQL query**: (I pulled this from another answer and altered for my use)

```
SELECT AvailStartTime, AvailEndTime 
FROM (SELECT @lastEndTime as AvailStartTime, StartTime as AvailEndTime, 
             @lastEndTime := EndTime 
      FROM (SELECT StartTime, EndTime 
            FROM app_bookings 
            WHERE doctor_id = 14 
            AND EndTime >= '2018-10-21 10:00' 
            AND StartTime < '2018-10-21 19:00' 
            ORDER BY StartTime
            ) e 
      JOIN (SELECT @lastEndTime := NULL) init) x WHERE 
            AvailEndTime > DATE_ADD(AvailStartTime, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

The following is output from the above query:

[image]

I go correct output using this query but I need to skip doctor lunchtime, lunch  start would be @startlunch "13:00" to "14:00" 
and got a record from 2018-10-21 15:30:00 to 2018-10-21 19:00 (skip if booked any entry)

Comment: So where the start time is less than 13, then the  end time is the 'least' value out of end time and 13?

Comment: we can define  and store in variable,
any option would be fine now.

Comment: This was my answer from your previous question that was put "on hold", abandoned, then deleted by the system: https://3v4l.org/eYSmV

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you so much, this is best answer for me again thank you.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really answer your new question -- which, frankly, I can't even follow.  Would you like to modify your question? or leave it as is?  This page needs to progress to a resolution somehow.

Comment: You might like to earn your Disciplined badge.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined